# $_POST Array from html form

Tags: php

I am trying to send data from multiple checkboxes (id[]) and create an array "info" in php to allow me to run a script for each value (however the quantity of values may change each time) however first I am trying to display the content of each array value. I am not quite sure how to put my array populating line to save all the content to the array.

HTML

```
echo("<input name='id[]' type='checkbox' value='".$shopnumb."'>");
```

my hopeful processing code currently is -

```
$info=$_POST['id[]'];
Echo(array_values($info));
```

what do I need to do to make the content sent by post from the form checkboxes populate the array info

any help is greatly appreciated

edited for clarification.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Change

```
$info=$_POST['id[]'];
```

to

```
$info=$_POST['id'];
```

by adding `[]` to the end of your form field names, PHP will automatically convert these variables into arrays.

Comment: thank you this was probably my biggest problem - I wasn't even thinking about it.

Answer (score 16):

You should get the array like in $_POST['id']. So you should be able to do this:

```
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . "<br />";
}
```

Input names should be same:

```
<input name='id[]' type='checkbox' value='1'>
<input name='id[]' type='checkbox' value='2'>
...
```

Comment: This is the only answer which really makes sense

Answer (score 8):

On the form page, field names must look like this

```
<input name="id[]" type="checkbox" value="x">
<input name="id[]" type="checkbox" value="y">
<input name="id[]" type="checkbox" value="z">
```

On the destination page, `$_POST['id']` is your array variable

```
$id = implode(",", $_POST['id']);
echo $id; //Should print "1,2,3"
```

You cannot echo an array directly, because it will just print out "Array". If you wanna print out the array values use `print_r`.

```
print_r($_POST['id']);
```

Comment: You used id[] which means that you are passing an array. This is used if you want to pass multiple checkboxes. If you just want to pass one checkbox just use name="id"

Comment: I am passing possibly 1 possibly 500

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand your question, but maybe:

```
foreach ($_POST as $id=>$value)
    if (strncmp($id,'id[',3) $info[rtrim(ltrim($id,'id['),']')]=$_POST[$id];
```

would help

That is if you really want to have a different name (id[key]) on each checkbox of the html form (not very efficient). If not you can just name them all the same, i.e. 'id' and iterate on the (selected) values of the array, like: `foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key=>$value)...`