# get user input as array and distribute it one by one

Tags: php

I am developing a website that can let the user buy something. The problem comes if the user buys many items at once.

For example:
User A bought item 1 with quantity 2
User B bought item 2 with quantity 1

I want the confirmation page to display:

```
You have bought 
Item 1, quantity: 2
Item 2, quantity: 1
```

The problem is that I can't find how to get each of the quantity based on the selected item. I am just able to display directly like this

```
You have bought
Item 1, quantity: 2 quantity 1
Item 2, quantity: 2 quantity 1
```

This is my user input form

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" hidden name=\"cart[]\" id=\"itemIDValue\" value=\" ".$itemID ."\"/>";
echo "<input type=\"text\" hidden name=\"qty[]\" value=\"".$itemQty."\">";
```

and this is my PHP code

```
$sql = "this will get all the data from database";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                  echo"<p> Brand : " . $row[4] . " </p>
                       <p> Name : " . $row[3] ."</p>";
            }
```

Basically I can get the item name and the brand correctly, but I can't get the quantity correctly for that particular item.

I tried to use foreach loop

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

             foreach($qty as $a => $value){
                  echo"<p> Brand : " . $row[0] . " </p>
                       <p> Name : " . $row[1] ."</p>
                       <p> Qty : " . $value . "</p>";
            }
 }
```

The foreach loop will give me what I want, but now the problem is, if the user bought 2 items, the data output will be repeated and as a result there will be 4 items(2 items x2)

Can anybody help me please? Any help given is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please tell us how the Database table is structured and the MYSQL Query you use. Probably you should group and count the found items.

Comment: the quantity here is not from database sir, it is from user input.

Comment: Ok Alvin, so why this line `$sql = "this will get all the data from database";`?

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676011/post-array-from-html-form

Comment: have a look at the dublicate-comment I made. that's your solution, I think.

Answer (score 0):

here's an adaption for your problem, 
already answered in that question (dublicate):

[$_POST Array from html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676011/post-array-from-html-form)

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    // that's what you need:
    $qty=$_POST['qty'];

    foreach($qty as $a => $value){
         echo"<p> Brand : " . $row[0] . " </p>
              <p> Name : " . $row[1] ."</p>
              <p> Qty : " . $value . "</p>";
    }
}
```