# How to handle processing of different values of the same name - php form

Tags: php, sql, forms, form-submit

I am trying to familiarize myself php, and I am running into a problem when processing a form. It is for a book library. 
Where each book could have more than one genre, the database is formatted to have a many-to-many relationship here.
I was able to display multiple genres associated with one book by going through a table and creating a new associative array of the all the genre name and id pairs associated with one book. I then loop through that array again to display multiple drop-downs through html select tags with all the genres as options and the one associated with the book selected.
That is how I solved displaying the data, but now when it comes to process of editing or adding a book's information, I cannot understand how I would go about a form submission where I have multiple values on the same name(in this example, "genre_id"). Do I have to create separate pages or separate submissions (POST request) somehow? Could I possibly submit an array and then unscramble it on the processing page, and if so, how? 
I'm not sure how to share my code on this question, as its more a question of "what would this code look like?". How do I approach this? How do I sort out these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html you can name your elements like name=‘myFromElement[]’. You could then use JS to allow a user to add as many of these inputs as they would like. PHP will recognize the elements as members of the array $_POST[‘myFormElement’]. You could then access all the data by looping through $_POST[‘myFormElement’].

See: [$_POST Array from html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676011/post-array-from-html-form)

Comment: This is helpful thank you. html is name="genre_id[]" on each of the select tags(working with 2 genres now) . On form processing page, when I do print_r($_POST); it is giving 1 value for "genre_id" but when try to loop through and echo $_POST["genre_id"] it says invalid argument and    $_POST["genre_id[]"] gives undefined index error. Im trying multiple different ways to loop through with same result. I am thinking only  one of the values is making it through on the actual POST request.

Comment: nevermind I am seeing how its an array! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when you add such options you should use checkboxes - than you can easy add many values to them. 
Example:

```
<label for="option1">Gender 1</label><input id="option1" name="gender[1]" value="y" type="checkbox" />
<label for="optionX">Gender X</label><input id="optionX" name="gender[x]" value="y" type="checkbox" />
```

Later in PHP you can just foreach on this elements:

```
if(isset($_POST['gender'])({
foreach($_POST['gender'] as $id => $val){
echo $id.' '.$val.'<br />';
}
}
```

In this example all gender id from other table will be in `$id` variable. In `label` you should put name there.
`optionX` and `gender[x]` don't need to have same "x" - value
in `label` element `for="option1"` MUST BE SAME as `id` in `input`