# Trouble adding some simple PHP form validation to check for empty form fields?

Tags: php, forms, validation, post

I have a form and am trying to add some basic security and validation to it:

I'm trying to create an `$error` variable to display error messages if fields are left blank.

Currently if I leave the name field and the radio button empty, I am only seeing an error message relating to the empty radio button and not the empty name field.

I am trying to keep this form as simple as possible, but just want to add some basic security and validation.

Can anybody help?

Her's my HTML form:

```
<?php
if(@$_REQUEST['submit'] == '1') {
    include('assets/forms/rsvp.php');
}
?>

        <form action="?" method="post">
            <?php if(@$errors) :?>
                <p class="errors"><?php echo $errors; ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1" />
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="field-l">
                    <p>Name</p>
                </div>
                <div class="field-r">
                    <p>Attending?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row guest">
                <div class="field-l">
                    <input type="text" name="name[0]" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
                </div>
                <div class="field-r">
                    <input type="radio" name="coming[0]" id="coming-yes" class="coming-yes" value="Yes"><label for="coming-yes">Yes</label><input type="radio" name="coming[0]" id="coming-no" class="coming-no" value="No"><label for="coming-no">No</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="addguest" href="#">Add further guest</a>
            <div class="form-row">
                <button type="submit" id="rsvp-submit" tabindex="2">Submit RSVP</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Here's my form process code:

```
<?php

//echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST, true) . "</pre>"; die();

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']));
}
if (isset($_POST['coming'])) {
    $coming = strip_tags(trim($_POST['coming']));
}

$errors = "";
if(!@$_POST['name'])    { $errors .= "Please enter your name.<br/>\n"; }
if(!@$_POST['coming'])  { $errors .= "Please enter yes or no for attending.<br/>\n"; }

if(@$_POST['emailaddress'] != '')   { $spam = '1'; }

if (!$errors && @$spam != '1')
    {
        $to = "example@xyz.com";
        $subject = "Wedding RSVP";
        $headers = "From: noreply@adrianandemma.com";
        $body = "The following RSVP has been sent via the website.\n\n";
        for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['name']); $i++) {
            $body .= "
            Name ".($i+1)." : " . $_POST['name'][$i] . "\n
            Coming ".($i+1)." : " . $_POST['coming'][$i] ."\n\n";
        }
        $body .= "\n\nDate Received: " . date("j F Y, g:i a") . "\n";

        mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
    }

?>
```

Comment: remove all the error suppression `@` from your code and start working through the errors

Comment: With the possible exception (no pun intended) of a few built in I/O functions, you should not use the error suppression symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're sending these POST variables [as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11676071/1255289), but treating them like a string. You need to [loop through each one](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) individually:

```
<?php
$errors = "";
foreach ($_POST["name"] as $index=>$name) {
    if (empty($name)) {
        $errors .= "Name missing from entry $index.<br/>\n";
    }
}
foreach ($_POST["coming"] as $index=>$coming) {
    if (empty($coming)) {
        $errors .= "Please enter attendance for entry $index.<br/>\n";
    }
}

if ($errors === "") {
    $to = "example@xyz.com";
    $subject = "Wedding RSVP";
    $headers = "From: noreply@adrianandemma.com";
    $body = "The following RSVP has been sent via the website.\n\n";
    foreach($_POST["name"] as $i=>$name) {
        $coming = $_POST["coming"][$i];
        $num = $i + 1;
        $body .= "Name $num : $name\nComing $num : $coming\n\n";
    }
    $body .= "\n\nDate Received: " . date("j F Y, g:i a") . "\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `empty()` would be enough to check.

```
if(empty($_POST['field'])){
 //Your code//
}
```

And for more security use `strlen()`

```
if(strlen($_POST['field']) == 0){
 //Your code//
}
```

combine both `if(strlen($field) < 0 || empty($field)){//code}`

Comment: `strlen` offers no "security," and will trigger notices if the array index does not exist. Your first suggestion is fine.

Comment: This works great if all fields have been left blank, but if somebody hits 'add further guest' fills in one name and yes/no row, but leaves the second one blank i still get the error messages. Not sure if there is a way around this...

Comment: @miken32 Isn't it usually used in forms validation to ensure the length of the entries? Please i'm concerned about why doesn't it offer any security.

Comment: I tried changing out to if(empty($_POST['name'])) { $errors .= "Please enter your name<br/>"; } but this doesn't seem to return an error message when the 'name' field is left blank...

Comment: `empty()` checks for an unset variable or index, or if it is set, for content that evaluates to boolean false (i.e. 0 or ''). `empty($foo)` is the same as `!isset($foo) || strlen($foo) === 0 || $foo === "0" || $foo === 0 || $foo === false`

Comment: @miken32 So in this case the only good use of `strlen()` is if i wanted to set a min length and max only?

Comment: Odd, I've now changed to if(!isset($name)) { $errors .= "Please enter your name<br/>"; } but it still only shows me the error message relating to the empty radio buttons.

Comment: Yes, `strlen` is good for checking length of a string. Not so good for checking the existence of a variable without throwing notices at you.

Answer (score -1):

if(strlen($_POST['name']) == 0 ){

$errors = "Please enter your name";

}
// strlen() == 0 means the name field is empty