# all input form data are posted but unable to retrieve array input using php

Tags: php, ajax

all inputs are retrieved but unable to get the array(sp_serail[]) value when I check count using PHP I got count 1 array(sp_serail[]) count but the actual count will be 3. I can retrieve all input but the only array is not working

I tried all the possibility
     ($serial_no = array($_POST['sp_serail[]']);
    //$serial_no = array($_POST['sp_serail']);)
When I submit all form data will posted I got output in google dev
tool(Network->header)->Form Data

user_id:4
       bar_code: 1234
    age_stock: 25
    eng_stock: 12
    sp_name: tst1
    sp_qty: 3
    sp_serail[]: 123457
    sp_serail[]: 123456
     sp_serail[]: 12345

```
<form action="issue_mat.php.php" id="Addqty" method="post">
```

```
                    <input list="eng_name" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="eng_mobile" id="eng_mobile" placeholder="Enter Eng Mobile">

                    <span class="fa fa-file form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  </div>
                         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" id="bar_code" name="bar_code" placeholder="BarCode">
                    <span class="fa fa-barcode form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  </div>

                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 ">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age_stock" name="age_stock" placeholder="WH Stock">

                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 ">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eng_stock" name="eng_stock" placeholder="Eng Stock">
                     <input type="hidden" id="sp_name" name="sp_name" value="tst1">

                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sp_qty" name="sp_qty" placeholder="QTY">
                     <input type="hidden" id="chk_sp_qty" name="chk_sp_qty" value="0">

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
                       <input list="serial no." class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="add_serial" id="add_serial" placeholder="Item Serial No.">

                    <span class="fa fa-plus-square-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                         </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="seral_list">
              <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                  <h2>Serial NO |<small>Added spare serial no.</small></h2>

                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="x_content">

                  <div class="">
                    <ul class="to_do" id="list_serial"><li><p>12345</p><span style="float:right; top:-20px; position: relative;"><i id="46" class="del_serial fa fa-close" style="font-size:12px;color:red"></i></span><input type="hidden" value="12345" name="sp_serail" id="sp_serail"></li><li><p>123456</p><span style="float:right; top:-20px; position: relative;"><i id="44" class="del_serial fa fa-close" style="font-size:12px;color:red"></i></span><input type="hidden" value="123456" name="sp_serail" id="sp_serail"></li>
```

```
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
       <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3" id="butt_ons" style="bottom:-90px; position:relative;">

                       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset">Reset</button>
                       <button type="submit" id="edit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                </form>

$("#Addqty").on('submit',(function(e) {

    $("#issue_data").html('');

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "system/issue_mat.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data){

     $("#issue_data").html(data);

        },
        error: function(){}             
   });
}));



`if($_POST['user_id']) {
    $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
     $bar_code=$_POST['bar_code'];
$sp_qty=$_POST['sp_qty'];
 $age_stock=$_POST['age_stock'];
$sp_name=$_POST['sp_name'];
$status=1;
$serial_no = array($_POST['sp_serail[]']);
//$serial_no = array($_POST['sp_serail']);
 $spr_count = count($serial_no);
 echo " $spr_count";


}
```

I want to retrieve all input with an actual array

Comment: instead of `$_POST['sp_serail[]']` have you tried `$_POST['sp_serail']`? if my memory serves me well, it should return an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\_POST Array from html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676011/post-array-from-html-form)

Comment: yes I tried already but still getting count 1 only

Comment: You could try `var_dump($_POST)` to see everything that's coming in on that POST. could be the frontend isn't sending what you expect

Comment: yes front end not sending the data but when we check with google dev.tool i got all the strings

Comment: Can you add the output of `var_dump($_POST)` to the question?

Comment: Also show the form.

Comment: Yes I tried with Var_dump then only i realized that front end not sending the data. and added the form

Comment: Don't create an array of array, if you have used `FormData` then it will give you the result as you access other arrays like object type.

Answer (score 0):

When an input has a name like `sp_serail[]`, PHP will put an array in `$_POST['sp_serail']`, it doesn't create `$_POST['sp_serail[]']`. So you need to do:

```
$serial_no = $_POST['sp_serail'];
$spr_count = count($serial_no);
```

Comment: Is the misspelling `serail` instead of `serial` intentional?

Comment: intentionally var. created

Answer (score 0):

Rectified and got the solution
Removed ($serial_no = array($_POST['sp_serail[]']);
//$serial_no = array($_POST['sp_serail']);)
becasue array post with array only no need to convert array into array