# I want to get values in PHP throughout a html form

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Im new to PHP and want to get these arrays to send by a form, but cant manage to store it in a variable and access them

HTML

```
<form action="./index.php" method="post">
<select name="multicheckbox[]" multiple="multiple" class="4colactive">
    <option value="LunVie" name="LunVie">Lunes a Viernes</option>
    <option value="LunSab" name="LunSab">Lunes a Sábados</option>
    <option value="Todos" name="Todos">Todos los días</option>
    <option value="Otros" name="Otros">Otros</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
  $values = $_POST["multicheckbox"];
  echo $values[2];
?>
```

Comment: Think you need square brackets on your post: `$_POST["multicheckbox"]`

Comment: (Is `multicheckbox` really such a good name for a _select_ field?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\_POST Array from html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676011/post-array-from-html-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multicheckbox` is an array, iterate over it.

```
foreach($_POST["multicheckbox"] as $check) {
    echo $check . "<br />\n";
}
```

Also note `option`s don't have `name`s, the `select` has a `name`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

```
<select name="multicheckbox[]" multiple="multiple" class="4colactive">
    <option value="LunVie">Lunes a Viernes</option>
    <option value="LunSab">Lunes a Sábados</option>
    <option value="Todos">Todos los días</option>
    <option value="Otros">Otros</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Right you are. Yet if I may offer a suggestion, and that's to use something to separate the values when echo'd. This can be accomplished in a few ways. Either by spaces, `<br>` type of thing, and adding `"\n"` at the end of those which will produce a nicely formatted HTML output.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Good idea. Thanks.

Comment: i keep getting an error that says **Undefined index: multicheckbox in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 5** and **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 5** @user3783243

Comment: That would indicate the form value is not always submitted. Use an `isset` or `!empty` in that case. `if(!empty($_POST["multicheckbox"])) { ... }`